# Including namespace module through RSpec config in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rspec, namespaces, ruby-1.9.3

I like to use RSpec's include configuration method to include modules which are
only for namespacing so that I don't have to use fully-qualified names for their
inner classes and modules. This worked fine with RSpec 2.11.0 in Ruby 1.9.2. But
now on Ruby 1.9.3 this doesn't work anymore. How can I get it working again?

Here an example foobar_spec.rb:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Foo
end

describe Foo::Bar do
  it "should work" do
    Bar.new
  end
end
```

If you call it by the following command:

```
rspec foobar_spec.rb
```

It will work in Ruby 1.9.2 just fine. But it will raise the following error in Ruby 1.9.3:

```
Failure/Error: Bar.new
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Bar
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [mailing list entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/ruby-talk-google/EhH0Ilctev4/nsHdrAviA7UJ) discusses the root change in 1.9.3 as to how constants are looked up, so it looks like a deliberate change.

You could scope the whole test, like this:

```
module Foo
  describe Bar do
    it "should work" do
      Bar.new
    end
  end
end
```

As another solution, you could extract the new object creation to a `before` or `let` or just define the object as the `subject` of the test.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the guys at the ruby-lang.org were really sure if this patch was actually a good idea. So I'm not sure about the "deliberate" thing.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to only have to specify the namespace once, then the idiomatic RSpec way is to use [described_class](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class). Like this:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

describe Foo::Bar do
  it "should work" do
    described_class.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Foo::Bar in the it block as well as in the describe argument.

Comment: Yeah. The whole thing here was to avoid having to do this, which worked in Ruby 1.9.2. And still works in Ruby 1.9.3 if you include one module into another, but somehow it doesn't work for RSpec anymore.

Comment: But.. in sam's defence, isn't that the point of name-spacing something? so you have to access it through the namespace?